iwd 802.1X EAP-TLS + personal certificates
In iwd, I am setting up an 802.1X EAP-TLS connection, configured in /var/lib/iwd, as described in iwd.network(5). According to this answer, the certificates must also go into the /var/lib/iwd directory, or iwd will not be able to read them.
Because the configuration resides in /var/lib/iwd, it will be accessible system-wide. I.e. every user will be able to connect to the wireless network using my personal certificates.
Certificates are personal and are not meant to be shared among all users of the system. What is "the correct" way of managing personalized certificates in iwd, when using 802.1X EAP-TLS? Or am I misunderstanding something?
